# Facing issues with 3d plot in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am reading data from the following csv file:

```
X   Y   Z
0.1 50  6.951
0.1 60  12.774
0.1 65  17.454
0.1 70  27.842
0.2 50  7.908
0.2 60  12.218
0.2 65  15.601
0.2 70  25.811
0.3 50  9.294
0.3 60  13.184
0.3 65  18.021
0.3 70  27.465
0.4 50  10.817
0.4 60  14.819
0.4 65  17.288
0.4 70  28.82
0.5 50  10.755
0.5 60  15.15
0.5 65  18.997
0.5 70  26.2
```

This is how I am trying to construct the plot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=major]
\addplot3 [surf,shader=faceted, samples=25,domain=0:2,y domain=0:1]
 table[x=X, y=Y, z=Z, col sep=comma] {3dData1.csv};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It generates the following:
[image]

It doesn't generate  surface plot. 
How can I make it surface plot?

Comment: Your code does not compile here. Also, I don't understand why you have `col sep=comma` but no commas in your data file.